# Sharing to WeChat: WeixinJSBridge is undefined

Tags: wechat, weixinjsbridge

I'm trying to implement sharing to WeChat on our site.

Accordingly to [docs](https://open.wechat.com/cgi-bin/newreadtemplate?t=overseas_open/docs/oa/web/js-sdk#overview), I have to load SDK from `http://res.wx.qq.com/open/js/jweixin-1.0.0.js`, configure it, and call  corresponding methods ([`onMenuShareAppMessage`](https://open.wechat.com/cgi-bin/newreadtemplate?t=overseas_open/docs/oa/web/js-sdk#sharing-apis) in my case).

I did all configuration, it seems that it's ok (no errors displayed, `wx.ready()` callback is executed), but when I call `wx` methods, nothing happens at all.

Reading SDK code (minified), I can see that everything is wrapped in constructions like `window.WeixinJSBridge ? WeixinJSBridge.doSmth() : doNothing()`. In my case `WeixinJSBridge` is undefined.

But what is that `WeixinJSBridge` and where should I get it? It's not described in docs. Googling it gives some pages on Chinese with same question – "WeixinJSBridge is undefined" and with no answer.

How to properly work with all this stuff?
Or, maybe I'm totally misunderstand the docs and sharing to WeChat from website is impossible at all? Please somebody explain.

Comment: I would like to suggest you to contact official support. It might sounds oddly but I get a updated documentation from support last time.

Answer (score 0):

Understood. That SDK is only for WeChat browser, built-in inside their mobile application. For other browsers SDK has no sense.

So yep, normally it's impossible to share content to WeChat from website.

Answer (score 0):

`WeixinJSBridge` is an object available once `http://res.wx.qq.com/open/js/jweixin-1.0.0.js` is loaded **inside the Wechat Web Browser**.

It's used specifically to start the payment process in Wechat App.

If you wanna test/debug it, download the wechat testing software for desktop here: https://mp.weixin.qq.com/wiki?action=doc&id=mp1455784140