# Implement WeChat social share button

Tags: share, wechat

I'm trying to find a way to implement Social Share button to share via WeChat (the same as we can do for the Twitter, Facebook, etc). Not the whole website, just copied link or selected good.

I've found the official docs with JS SDK of Weixin API: https://developers.weixin.qq.com/doc/offiaccount/en/OA_Web_Apps/JS-SDK.html#10 , but [according to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51474786/sharing-to-wechat-weixinjsbridge-is-undefined) it works only with the integrated WeChat browser.

WeChat also doesn't allow to use deeplink directly to the app (like `weixin://dl/posts`), so there are also no way to implement direct sharing with passing params.

Is there any possibilities to share content via WeChat from non-WeChat browser (like Chrome, Safari, etc)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I hope edited version of the question satisfies the requirements. Let me know please if it's still might be unclear for users! @Community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone still searching for any solution, some sort of workaround for mobile devices might be [Web Share Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Share_API) .

*Note: Be careful, it doesn't have good browser support: https://caniuse.com/web-share*